# Where is the config stored that rails uses to generate the gemfile for new projects?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, gemfile

When doing a "rails new x" a gemfile is created for the project, which bundler then uses to auto install the required gems.

I know that this file can be edited after it is created, but I would like to change the gem versions Rails puts into the file by default. Where can I find the gem information Rails is referencing? How do I get at the source so that every new project gemfile starts out with the correct versions?

The gem versions installed do not appear to directly correspond to the Rails reference point (where ever it is) because I can change the installed gem version but Rails will continue to create project gemfiles with the previous gem version (bad) and then bundler will try to reinstall that version (worse).

Thanks,
Daniel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a template file that lives in the Rails codebase:

https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/railties/lib/rails/generators/rails/app/templates/Gemfile